# How would you optimize pagination queries in a graph database in Neo4J?

Tags: database, indexing, neo4j

For my graph database, I have users and transactions. Each user has an id. Each transaction has an id, date and sender and receiver. The sender and receiver of a transaction have the type `User`.id.

There is a sender/receiver type edge that connects users and transactions together.

I would like to query the 10 most recent transactions for a particular user, `user_id`, before they sent an arbitrary transaction with the id of `txn_id`.

How can I optimize the performance of this pagination query? I was thinking of creating a single index for both `User.id` to find `user_id` fast. If I index `Transaction.date` and `Transaction.id`, would it make it performant to search for a transaction that is older `txn_id` for an individual user?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about a composite index (`create index on :Transaction(date, id)`) then no, as you would need to have the exact values for lookup for the indexed properties. Any other means of lookup (including range scans) won't use the composite index.

An index on just :Transaction(date) won't help either, as this wouldn't be used once you found your user in question and expanded out the transactions. Starting from transactions by date wouldn't be wise, since you would receive many that weren't associated with the user in question.

You'll need an index on :User(id) for that quick lookup of the user, then you'll just need to use ordering with a limit to find the 10 most recent for the user.

If there can be a great many transactions per user, you might consider creating a linked list between transactions in date order so they can be iterated through much faster. Keep in mind that this would require keeping order as transactions are added, and you'd need to use proper locking techniques to avoid race conditions as you add on to the transactions list.